# How do I migrate an Artifactory repo to a shared filesystem repo?

Tags: sbt, ivy, artifactory

I teach high school computer science using Scala and I've managed to set up an Artifactory repo so that when my students download dependencies, we're doing most of our downloading inside the lab, rather than over the internet.

However, all our home folders are on a network drive and the terminals the students use don't have their own hard disks, so it seems silly to have dozens of copies of the same dependencies. Unfortunately, even with an Artifactory repo, SBT/Ivy copies all the artifacts into each user's ~/.ivy2/cache directory.

I've heard that, if I set up a shared filesystem repo then the artifacts won't be copied. What I can't figure out is how to export all the artifacts that Artifactory has cached for me in a format that would be recognized as a filesystem repo. (Exporting normally puts each remote repo in a separate folder that I suppose I'd have to somehow unify, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that. If that's the easiest thing to do, please explain how carefully.)

What I think I'd like to export is the `remote-repos` virtual repository, but that's not available as a choice on the Export page.

The other tricky part of this is that the same build file should be usable at home, where there is no proxy repo, so I'm relying on the fact that I can use `/etc/sbt/sbtopts` to override the repository resolution within the lab environment.

Comment: As often happens, after I submitted this, I had a brain-storm. If I let SBT copy all the dependencies for my projects into my ~/.ivy2/cache, could I then copy the contents into a directory and label that as my shared filesystem repo?

Answer (score 1):

### Change Ivy home

Define your `sbt` script with `${SBT_OPTS}`:

```
exec java -Xmx1512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M ${SBT_OPTS} -jar /etc/sbt/sbt-launch-0.13.0.jar "$@"
```

Then only in your network environment set `SBT_OPTS` as:

```
$ export SBT_OPTS="-Dsbt.ivy.home=/etc/sbt/repository"
```

The students probably need writing rights to the dir.

Comment: Will this cause problems with locking if the ivy home is a shared network directory?

Comment: Since multiple projects can share ivy home on a single machine, I'm hoping it'd be ok.

Answer (score 0):

What you also can do is use `davfs2` on Linux or "web folders" on Windows to simply mount Artifactory as a WebDAV resource (read-only). This avoids any indirection via a local file system, and keeping such a copy up to date.

Comment: Any Artifactory local or cache repository may be mounted as a secure WebDAV share and made browsable from any WebDAV-supporting file manager, by referencing the URL of the target repository.

Comment: Ooooh! This has promise. Of course, it means I have to figure out how davfs2 works. (sigh) Let me give this a try at school tomorrow, and this may just be the winning answer.

Comment: If on Linux, you don't really need to, see https://github.com/jhermann/artifactory-debian/blob/master/indexing/deb-index.sh#L44 (and also read the project ReadMe).

Comment: Still haven't had a chance to get this working, but it's still on the to-do list. Will let you know (and check the answer) when I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

### Unmanaged dependency

How about a solution that will get you out of Ivy?

In your original build using managed dependency, run

```
> show full-classpath
```

This should display something like the following:

```
[info]  List(Attributed(/home/foo/helloworld/target/scala-2.10/classes), Attributed(/home/foo/.ivy2/cache/com.eed3si9n/treehugger_2.10/jars/treehugger_2.10-0.3.0.jar), Attributed(/foo/.sbt/0.13.0/boot/scala-2.10.2/lib/scala-library.jar), Attributed(/home/foo/.ivy2/cache/com.github.scopt/scopt_2.10/jars/scopt_2.10-3.0.0.jar))
```

Create a directory named `/shared/project1/lib` or something and copy all the above jars in there, except for `scala-library.jar`.

Next, make a copy of your build and replace `libraryDependency` with the following:

```
unmanagedBase := file("/shared/project1/lib")
```

You should still be able to compile the code.

Comment: I had a comment in here that explained that the only problem with this approach is that it works in the lab, but doesn't transfer to home. Using /etc/sbt/sbtopts, I can override repo resolution for the lab accounts, but still allow students to download from the repos on their home machines. I don't know where the comment went, or maybe I just dreamt it.

Comment: Could you update the question to include that requirement? You don't want Ivy cache to be duplicated across the terminal sessions, but want the build file to be usable outside of your environment?